# XML Datasource and Gridview

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I have an XML file created when a process is being run and the location of that file is stored in **GlobalClass.GlobalUrl**

I have a grid view and after completing the process, connect the gridview to an xml datasource. this is the code that is have

```
XmlDataSource1.DataFile = GlobalClass.GlobalUrl
XmlDataSource1.DataBind()

GridView1.DataSource = "XmlDataSource1"
GridView1.DataBind()


Item
Select  X
Select  m
Select  l
Select  D
Select  a
Select  t
Select  a
Select  S
Select  o
Select  u
Select  r
Select  c
Select  e
Select  1
```

That is the output that i get. Some help please. by the way, the the GlobalClass.GlobalUrl is a path to an XML file

Comment: I'm not clear on what your xml datasource actually is? Is it a path to a file? If so, there is more that has to be done with it before you can bind it.

Comment: its a path to an XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is convert the xml to a dataset - using the ReadXml(). Then set the data source and bind it. Something like this:

```
DataSet xmlDataSet = new DataSet();
xmlDataSet.ReadXml("D:\\xmlPath");

GridView1.DataSource = xmlData.Tables[0];
GridVIew1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks this helps. Just gotta figure out how to format gridview.

Comment: If I answered it... don't forget to set it as answered :) thanks!